# Python_io in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, io

I'm having trouble working with tensorflow. I want to use `TFRecordWriter()` as below:

```
with tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(testing_filename) as tfrecord_writer:
    # do sth
```

but I get the error:

> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'python_io'

I'm working with tensorflow 1.2 and python 3.

How can I fix the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you double check your TF version? `print(tf.__version__)` You can also look at the loaded attributes of the tensorflow module: `print(dir(tf))`

Comment: @robert_x44 I've checked just now. The output of the `print(dir(tf))` is `['__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']` and the output of `tf.__version__` is an AttributeError, but I'm pretty sure its version is 1.2

Comment: If that's your `dir(tf)` something is not loading properly.  Is this your first attempt at a tensorflow program?  It may not be installed properly.  `tf.__version__` being an attribute error is a good indication something is wrong.  I'm assuming you have `import tensorflow as tf` based on your error message.

Comment: @robert_x44 It wasn't my first program in tensorflow. 
I've reinstalled the tensorflow and it works properly now. I don't know what the problem was, but it's fixed now. Thanks.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The problem in the (python_io) :

```
with tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(testing_filename) as tfrecord_writer:
# do sth
```

changed it to:

```
with tf.io.TFRecordWriter(testing_filename) as tfrecord_writer:
# do sth
```

Comment: Applies For TF2

Answer (score 3):

Use this instead :

```
tf.python.python_io
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and it turned out to be a corrupt tensorflow installation. I removed tensor flow and reinstalled and it worked for me afterwards.

```
$ pip3 uninstall tensorflow
$ pip3 install tensorflow
```

Comment: how was yours a corrupt tesorflow installation?

Answer (score -1):

it was in tensorflow v1 and there is no `tf.python_io` or `tf.python` in v2.
but still, you can use `tf.compat.v1.python_io` which is deprecated.

also, I would like to suggest you read the documents to use the new function instead of the deprecated ones.