# Tensorflow-gpu, has no attribute "python_io"

Tags: tensorflow, windows-10, tfrecord

I am trying to create a custom TFrecords.
When I called a script that uses the `tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(..)` as ...:
this error came up 
log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "createtfrecordsbyother.py", line 105, in <module>
    main(args)
  File "createtfrecordsbyother.py", line 85, in main
    num_shards=num_shards_train)
  File "createtfrecordsbyother.py", line 45, in create_tfrecords
    with tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(output_filename) as tfrecord_writer:
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'python_io'
```

Comment: By the way I tried reinstall. Error still there

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44863477/python-io-in-tensorflow

Comment: That is a attempt to fix it,with pasting method. But after a restart, the error came back. I am also using a virtual environment,of python 3.7.4 with Cuda and CuDnn downloaded,installed CUDA,and had paste the content in CuDnn to CUDA..Checked the tensorflow with a script it showed my Nvidia gpu.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56176167/how-to-use-tf-python-io-tfrecordwriter-in-tensorflow-2-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switched to the tensorflow,ver1.15 .

After switching to that version that error is gone and replaced with a warning that states module is depreciated with a new name (io) instead of (python_io)

Note many modules also changed the name.
and downgrading tensorflow may require a updates of CUDA and Cudnn library.

It's not a complete solution to those who wanted to stay in Tensorflow2.0-gpu

But I will post this as a solution for those who are like me fine with downgrade to 1.15.

For uninstall tf,please refer to tf official documentation under install page.

and after this answer is posted there are others that encounter similar problems with more answers, [How to use tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter in Tensorflow 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56176167/how-to-use-tf-python-io-tfrecordwriter-in-tensorflow-2-0)